# Internet Explorer 8 causing a Windows Forms to unexpectedly close?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have an enterprise application deployed with ClickOnce in 20+ machines with Windows XP showing bizarre issues in only 2 of them. After opening IE and the user tries to open my application, the login form shows up in the screen normally. But when the user tries to type the username and password, the application suddenly closes without throwing errors.
If the user doesn't open IE the application runs normally.
Tried killing almost all processes in task list with no success, tried using a try/catch in the Main method but caught no exceptions. Nothing is logged to the Event Log.
Any tips?

Comment: Does your application have a web browser control in it? You also need to be looking into what's different about the 2 machines where it fails (IE version, Windows Update etc.)

Comment: You are going to have to do the leg work.  Bring a configured machine and a nice present.  Starbuck is kinda lame, I recommend the extraordinary La Florentine Torrone nougat.  Only eleven bucks for 18 pieces at Amazon.com, it says you care on each individually wrapped piece.  Swap the machine, run a debugger on it.

Comment: @ChrisF No, it doesn't. Guess I'll need to check everything. But why does it happen itrigues me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an online banking plugin for IE that caused my application to be shut down. Still not solved, as the plugin wrongly thinks that my application could be harmful.